# Casting String to Money Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, ssis

Is there a simple built-in way of converting NVARCHARs in the format "$1,000.00" and "($1,000.00)" to the numerical values 1000.00 and -1000.00 respectively?

I'm trying to do this in either SQL Server or SSIS.

Casting to MONEY gives me the error

```
"Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.".
```

when attempting to cast the negative value, I'm assuming due to the parenthesis.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2012, you can use the [**`PARSE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT   '$1,000.00'
        ,CAST('$1,000.00' AS MONEY)
        ,CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('($1,000.00)', '(', '-'), ')','') AS MONEY)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1153)

And per @mellamokb's suggestion, if you're using SQL 2012, you can use this:

```
SELECT PARSE('($1000.00)' AS MONEY)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/78)

Comment: The OP has the error on the negative value, not the positive value: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1152

Comment: Updated with a solution for negative

Comment: Cool.  I didn't realize that money would parse the parentheses as well as the commas.